# Gentoo XEN host + EFI + MDADM + IMSM RAID5

Tags: linux, xen, mdadm, uefi

I have a workstation with a working Gentoo setup. It uses IMSM FakeRAID (level 5) with 4 disks. Booting done without bootloader using Linux kernel EFI STUB.

System works fine. Now I need to setup XEN HVM host on this station. Problem is that I'm unable to assemble IMSM array if booting with xen.efi. Direct kernel boot works just fine.

`mdadm --detail-platform` in initramfs w/ xen.efi gives me

> mdmon: imsm capabilities not found for controller: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2 (type SATA)

Anyone know if XEN works with mdadm on imsm raid5 or is it known issue? And also possible solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root of the problem was found.

While booting with native XEN UEFI intarface xen.efi microkernel does not expose EFI Variables to the Dom0 kernel.

As a result, **efivars** modules is not loaded and not providing any /sys/ entries required for mdadm to assemble IMSM firmware RAID.

Patching of the XEN package is required to achieve desired results.

Comment: It seems we have some progress on XEN side. Developers properly exposed variables and my machine is now booting fine. But nVidia graphics won't work! Arrghh...

Answer (score -2):

```
export IMSM_TEST_OROM=1
```

May change where `mdadm` gets `$IMSM` info from.